# Expand my RAID 5 volume without losing the data

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server, raid-5

In HP ProLiant ML-370 G6 (Windows Server 2008 R2). I have three HDD 147 GB each in my existing array RAID 5. Now I want to extend the existing array by adding two more 147 GB each extra HDD but I don't want to lose my current data or go through the process of setting everything up again from scratch. Can any one help me?

Comment: Software or hardware RAID?

Comment: ......Software RAID

Comment: My math says you have a max of 300gb of data, and a 2tb hdd is $54 approx.  Backup and go, problem solved??  Why are you wasting time with 147gb hdd?  A single SSD will probably beat the performance of all of them.  A 1tb ssd will offer more capacity than the drives you have plus the drives you are adding.  3 sdd sata = 1500mb/s your array is left in the dust. Plus you will save a lot of electricity.

Comment: Yes bro you are very right but i was just trying to save the time .Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend like that / migrate only if you have BBWC or FBWC. Otherwise, those options are not available in the Array Configuration Utility.

Comment: Is there any other tool  available like Hp array configuration utility, to expand the current array ? @Overmind

Comment: Unfortunately the tools are quite exclusive.